# How to attach a wall plate to an old junction box with different screw hole spacing?

Tags: electrical

I have two round junction boxes on top of my mantle that were used to support sconces.

I removed the sconces and want to cover the hole. The junction box screw holes are 2.75" apart. I can not find any cover plates that have those screw spacings.

How do I mount a wall plate with different screw spacings to that junction box?

Currently I have a rectangular wall plate covering it with only **one screw** in place until I find the better solution.

Is an option to get a large double rectangular plate and mount with 4 wall screws and attach directly to the wall? Is this considered "to code"?

Comment: Why not drill new holes in any suitably sized cover plate?

Comment: Something like this perhaps: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B000HM5M4K/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_HQOlAbT1GE2PT

Comment: 2.75" is a standard spacing for a lamp box, you might be dealing with a 3.5” lamp box, but I doubt it.  If your supplier doesn't have a lid for that, he's terrible, try a genuine electrical supply house. They are mostly one-off family owned businesses.

Comment: Searching on "2.75" round lamp box cover" got several hits, though the box size is evidently 3.25" for that hole spacing, and might be an alternate search term to try. There are also plastic covers that have no visible screw holes (they snap to a plastic part that's screwed into the box.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have there is a 3-1/2" round junction box intended for lamps.  That is a standard size, though largely obsolete today in favor of 4" round.

A 3-1/2" round junction box cover should do the job.  Most well equipped hardware stores and every electrical supply will sell it.

You might also find decorator covers but look for ones that will work with 3-1/2" round boxes.