# Install rectangular bracket on small 3" round junction box

Tags: electrical

I am trying to install 6 new wall lights. The old lights had a standard round bracket, but the new lights have a rectangular bracket (see photo) with holes that are not really designed to line up with anything -- they are designed to just screw into a wall. This is a small box - 3" between the screws and the box is slightly inset on the wood wall. I can't find any crossbar or plate that would work. I'm thinking I have to cut a round piece of 1/8" plywood -- but then the junction box is covered with wood, which doesn't seem safe. Looking for ideas[image]

Comment: why are the new brackets L shaped

Comment: are you saying the holes from the new bracket do not align with the screws in the wall socket ?

Comment: Show me how the light mounts to the bracket, with what screws.

Comment: you are missing the Light Fixture Mounting Bracket, Universal Crossbar

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The metal bracket is supposed to bolt to the wall, and electric wires then connect into a harness that is inside the light. That square back of the light slips over the metal bracket on the wall and you tighten a tiny lock screw. So the challenge is that metal bracket only has two little holes, nowhere near the holes on the junction box in the wall. I'm thinking actually plywood might be ok to solve this because the electrical connection is actually inside the light, not inside the junction box.

Comment: @BromB The wires would still go through the plywood, so damage to the wires could cause arcing and ignite the plywood. High density polyethylene (HDPE, often used in cutting boards) is easily cut and shaped with the same tools and fasteners as wood, is not flammable and won't rot. I find it a useful alternative to using plywood.

Answer (score 1):

**Extenders** for electrical boxes are typically called "**mud rings**" or "**extender rings**". Do a search and you'll find an amazing number of sizes and shapes, both metallic and non-metallic.

Example only of one type:

[image]

Another option is a small plastic bushing that fits around each screw that holds the fixture/bracket to the junction box and acts as a spacer between fixture and box so the screw is secure. You can stack them for your specific gap thickness.
Example only:

[image]

See also this previous question: [how-to-attach-a-wall-plate-to-an-old-junction-box-with-different-screw-hole-spac](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/128815/how-to-attach-a-wall-plate-to-an-old-junction-box-with-different-screw-hole-spac)